# How to display the image after I use imagecopymerge?

Tags: php

I tried this simple code

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('twi.jpg');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('twi.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 453, 590, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

When I tried to run the script on WAMP, it says image can't be display because it contains error. Is there anything else I need to include in the script to make it work?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? remove your header to check

Comment: if I remove the header, I get bunch of these text which make no sense "ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀNÅ"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ"

Comment: if you get a bunch of text which makes no sense i would say your image is fine. in your post you say: `image can't be display because it contains error` what is the error?

Comment: The problem is I don't know what the error is.

Comment: This is the output on the webpage <img src="http://127.0.0.1/testimage.php" alt="The image “http://127.0.0.1/testimage.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.">

Comment: your code is working fine for me. are you sure the path to the image is correct?

Comment: yes. The image is located in the same dir as my testimage.php

Comment: may be problem is in you twi.jpg. have you placed this image in your project folder? check the image path.

Comment: @ripa i just asked the same :P

Comment: check if you have any trailing whitespaces before you open the <?php ?> tag

Comment: It's working!! Thanks Robin. There was an empty line.

Comment: check whether GD library is on to your server or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me.

Check for any trailing whitespaces before the  tag